Windbg !ext.heap commands failure
Windbg !ext.heap -p commands are not working , Only !heap and !exts.heap -s are working on Windows 10.
I have loaded all symbols from srv*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols, I tried reloading the symbols using .symfix and .reload -f, but still no result.
!ext.heap -p -a <address> just gives blank output, even no errors.
I am analyzing a running process and have enabled page heap before starting the process.

What kind of dumps are you trying to analyze? There are quite a few cases that this command might fail so you have to edit the question to specify more contexts.

i am attached to running process & I Have enable page heap
